# Simplified Linq for return to View Model

Tags: linq

How do I simplified the below statement?

```
var Orders = db.Orders
               .Include(o => o.shipment)
               .Where(o => o.ID == 3 || o.ID == 5 || o.ID == 10)
               .ToList();
```

Ultimately, I would like to do like:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE ID IN (3,5,10)
```

in strongly typed Entity to return to View model

I've tried `.Any`, `.Contains` or `.Intersect` but cannot "form" the Linq query.

Comment: I'm assuming this is a typo, but you check `o.ID == 3 && o.ID == 5 && o.ID == 10` which will (probably) never be true. Assuming the SQL is right, you want `||`. Again, probably just a typo in copying it into here, but I thought I'd mention that.

Comment: The below answers do, I suppose, somewhat simplify the query. But I feel like what you already have is simple enough. Are you sure it's worth the overhead of having another array to store the numbers?

Comment: Yes, I just made up an example, you are right, it's OR (||). However, I got the answer right. as commented below. Sorry, I can't (not enough rights to) edit my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var items = new int[] {3,5,10};
var Orders = db.Orders
               .Include(o => o.shipment)
               .Where(o => items.Contains(o.ID))
               .ToList();
```

Comment: I have tried something like that, but got red underline saying that the best overloaded method...has some invalid argument. at items.Contains(o.ID) This is the part I am headache with. Thanks for you suggestion anyway.

Comment: @Gian is `ID` an int? If not, change the type of `items` to whatever it *is*. For instance, `new long[] {3, 5, 10 }` or what have you.

Comment: ID data type is same as database data type. May be nullable.

Comment: Thank to Matthew Haugen on the little question mark reminder. And yes, thanks to BrokenGlass (oops, use contact lens then). I just can't believe the nullable and not nullable issue.

Answer (score 1):

How about this ?

```
List<int> items = new List<int>(new []{3,5,10});

var Orders = db.Orders
               .Include(o => o.shipment)
               .Where(o => items.Contains(o.ID))
               .ToList();
```

In place of `int` you should use the same datatype as of `ID`

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: You are hard-coding 3,4,10. Sorry, my sample was just an example, I would like to suppose that is from a TList<>. Thanks for you suggestion,

Comment: @Gian We can have a dynamic array at this place. This one is just an example.